# How do I solve inequalities with Sympy?

Tags: python, sympy, equation-solving, inequalities

**Objective:** I want to implement a Fourier-Motzkin Elimination using Sympy. The first step for this would be to solve a number of inequalities.

**Problem:** The tools for solving inequalities with Sympy like solveset, solve_poly_inequality or reduce_inequalities do no seem to work.

**Data:**

```
from sympy import *
u1, u2, x1, x2 = symbols('u1 u2 x1 x2')
y1, y2, y3, y4, y5 = symbols('y1 y2 y3 y4 y5')

list_of_inequalities = [50*u2 - y5, -x2 + y5, 0, -u2 + 1, -35*u2 + y4 + y5, 35*u2 + x1 + x2 - y4 - y5 - 35, 35*u2 - y4 - y5, -35*u2 - x1 - x2 + y4 + y5 + 35, 50*y1 - y4, 50*u1 - x1 - 50*y1 + y4, -50*y1 + y4, -50*u1 + x1 + 50*y1 - y4, u2 - y1, -u1 - u2 + y1 + 1, 50*u2 - y5, -50*u2 - x2 + y5 + 50, 65*y1, 65*u1 - 65*y1, 35*u2 + 65*y1 - y4 - y5]
```

These are all expressions that are `>=0`.
I want to get rid of all the y-variables with Fourier-Motzkin Elimination. So, in a first step I would like to start with `y1`.

**Desired Solution:**

For example for `list_of_inequalites[8]` which is `50*y1 - y4` I should get `y1>=y4/50` or similar.
In the end I want to have two lists. One with expressions that are smaller than `y1` which would contain `y4/50` and one with expressions larger than `y1`.
I will need these lists for the next step in the Fourier-Motzkin Elimination.

**My Try:**

```
y_1=[]
for eq in list_of_equations:
    expr= eq>=0
    if y1 in eq.free_symbols:
        y_1.append(solveset(expr.lhs>=0,y1,domain=S.Reals))
```

This way I get a list like this:

```
[ConditionSet(y1, 50*y1 - y4 >= 0, Reals), ConditionSet(y1, 50*u1 - x1 - 50*y1 + y4 >= 0, Reals), ConditionSet(y1, -50*y1 + y4 >= 0, Reals), ConditionSet(y1, -50*u1 + x1 + 50*y1 - y4 >= 0, Reals), ConditionSet(y1, u2 - y1 >= 0, Reals), ConditionSet(y1, -u1 - u2 + y1 + 1 >= 0, Reals), Interval(0, oo), ConditionSet(y1, 65*u1 - 65*y1 >= 0, Reals), ConditionSet(y1, 35*u2 + 65*y1 - y4 - y5 >= 0, Reals)]
```

I do not understand how to deal with these ConditionSets. They are certainly not the solution of my problem.

Another way would be to work with solve_poly_inequality:

```
for eq in list_of_equations:   
    expr= eq>=0
    if y1 in eq.free_symbols:
        y_1.append(solve_poly_inequality(Poly(expr.lhs,y1),'>='))
```

This way I get a

```
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-269-686426e9455b> in <module>
      9     expr= eq>=0
     10     if y1 in eq.free_symbols:
---> 11         y_1.append(solve_poly_inequality(Poly(expr.lhs,y1),'>='))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\inequalities.py in solve_poly_inequality(poly, rel)
     56                 "could not determine truth value of %s" % t)
     57 
---> 58     reals, intervals = poly.real_roots(multiple=False), []
     59 
     60     if rel == '==':

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\polytools.py in real_roots(f, multiple, radicals)
   3498 
   3499         """
-> 3500         reals = sympy.polys.rootoftools.CRootOf.real_roots(f, radicals=radicals)
   3501 
   3502         if multiple:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\rootoftools.py in real_roots(cls, poly, radicals)
    385     def real_roots(cls, poly, radicals=True):
    386         """Get real roots of a polynomial. """
--> 387         return cls._get_roots("_real_roots", poly, radicals)
    388 
    389     @classmethod

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\rootoftools.py in _get_roots(cls, method, poly, radicals)
    717             raise PolynomialError("only univariate polynomials are allowed")
    718 
--> 719         coeff, poly = cls._preprocess_roots(poly)
    720         roots = []
    721 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\rootoftools.py in _preprocess_roots(cls, poly)
    696         if not dom.is_ZZ:
    697             raise NotImplementedError(
--> 698                 "sorted roots not supported over %s" % dom)
    699 
    700         return coeff, poly

NotImplementedError: sorted roots not supported over ZZ[x1,y4,u1]
```

The inequality that causes this error is `50*u1 - x1 - 50*y1 + y4 >= 0`.

The last way I found for solving inequalities is reduce_inequalities:

```
for eq in list_of_equations:   
    expr= eq>=0
    if y1 in eq.free_symbols:
        y_1.append(reduce_inequalities(expr>=0,[y1]))
```

But, this time I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-266-50cdf532f9fa> in <module>
     22     expr= eq>=0
     23     if y1 in eq.free_symbols:
---> 24         y_1.append(reduce_inequalities(expr>=0,[y1]))
     25 #     print(y_1[-1])
     26 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\inequalities.py in reduce_inequalities(inequalities, symbols)
    985 
    986     # solve system
--> 987     rv = _reduce_inequalities(inequalities, symbols)
    988 
    989     # restore original symbols and return

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\inequalities.py in _reduce_inequalities(inequalities, symbols)
    900             if len(common) == 1:
    901                 gen = common.pop()
--> 902                 other.append(_solve_inequality(Relational(expr, 0, rel), gen))
    903                 continue
    904             else:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\relational.py in __new__(cls, lhs, rhs, rop, **assumptions)
     87                             Eq and Ne; all other relationals expect
     88                             real expressions.
---> 89                         '''))
     90             # \\\
     91             return rv
TypeError: 
A Boolean argument can only be used in Eq and Ne; all other
relationals expect real expressions.
```

Do you have any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Comment: When you ask about an error, show the **whole thing**!  For example what actually produces the `truth value` error?  `if y>0: print('yes')` produces that error, since `y>0` is a symbolic relation, which can't be used in a context like `if` with expects a simple True/False.

Comment: Hmm, actually I couldn't reproduce the ````truth value```` error, but got ````NotImplementedError: sorted roots not supported over ZZ[x1,y4,u1]````.
Otherwise, I now included the whole error.

Comment: There is some work [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/22389) with a reference to another approach there, too.

Comment: `u1, u2, x1, x2 = smp.symbols('u1 u2 x1 x2')`

gives

`NameError: name 'smp' is not defined`

Comment: This looks like it's using iPython and Anaconda - infrequently restarting the kernel and re-running all the cells or copying the relevant parts to a simple script may help a great amount with debugging (for example as @Nasser shows, there's probably at least a line with `import sympy as smp` not shown amongst any amount of others..)

Comment: I restarted the kernel and re-ran all the cells in a simple script. But, the errors are exactly the same. I also got rid of the 'smp'.

Comment: Beyond some basics it is hard to generalize `sympy` solutions.  You have to study the docs.  I haven't done much with inequalities, or what I think is being called `relationals`.  And if your `solve_set` produces `ConditionSets`, then you need to study that part of the documentation.  Also the coverage of subpackages varies widely; this is a open source project, not something that was developed and maintained by a company with paid staff.

Comment: Is there any other way to solve linear inequalities with Python? I actually solved the example problem by hand. So I could also start to work with string manipulations to solve it. I just thought Sympy should have a way to solve this easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly the nature of your particular problem. But maybe we can work around it.

#### First solution

`solve` is also capable of solving inequalities, though it might not be easy to extract the proper solution:

```
sols = [solve(t >= 0, y1) for t in list_of_inequalities if y1 in S(t).free_symbols]
sols

# [(y1 < oo) & (y1 >= y4/50),
#  (-oo < y1) & (y1 <= u1 - x1/50 + y4/50),
#  (-oo < y1) & (y1 <= y4/50),
#  (y1 < oo) & (y1 >= u1 - x1/50 + y4/50),
#  (y1 <= u2) & (-oo < y1),
#  (y1 < oo) & (y1 >= u1 + u2 - 1),
#  (0 <= y1) & (y1 < oo),
#  (y1 <= u1) & (-oo < y1),
#  (y1 < oo) & (y1 >= -7*u2/13 + y4/65 + y5/65)]

# now a bit of post-processing:
from sympy.core.numbers import Infinity, NegativeInfinity
test_inf = lambda x: x.has(Infinity) or x.has(NegativeInfinity)
correct_arg = lambda x, y: x.args[0] if not x.args[0].has(y) else x.args[1]
final = [
    correct_arg(u, y1) for u in # extract the arguments from Relational that doesn't contain y1
    [t[0] if not test_inf(t[0]) else t[1] for t in # exclude arguments containing infinity
    [s.args[:2] for s in sols]] # extract args from Boolean And
]
final

# [y4/50,
#  u1 - x1/50 + y4/50,
#  y4/50,
#  u1 - x1/50 + y4/50,
#  u2,
#  u1 + u2 - 1,
#  0,
#  u1,
#  -7*u2/13 + y4/65 + y5/65]
```

#### Second solution

Since your inequalities appear to be linear, maybe we can solve them as equations, thus sparing us some post-processing. For example:

```py
sols = [solve(t, y1)[0] for t in list_of_inequalities if y1 in S(t).free_symbols]
sols

# [y4/50,
#  u1 - x1/50 + y4/50,
#  y4/50,
#  u1 - x1/50 + y4/50,
#  u2,
#  u1 + u2 - 1,
#  0,
#  u1,
#  -7*u2/13 + y4/65 + y5/65]
```

#### Third solution

I believe that `solveset` returned `ConditionSet` because it doesn't know the nature of your symbols. If your symbols represent real variables, you can set assumptions on them:

```py
u1, u2, x1, x2 = symbols('u1 u2 x1 x2', real=True)
y1, y2, y3, y4, y5 = symbols('y1 y2 y3 y4 y5', real=True)

list_of_inequalities = [50*u2 - y5, -x2 + y5, 0, -u2 + 1, -35*u2 + y4 + y5, 35*u2 + x1 + x2 - y4 - y5 - 35, 35*u2 - y4 - y5, -35*u2 - x1 - x2 + y4 + y5 + 35, 50*y1 - y4, 50*u1 - x1 - 50*y1 + y4, -50*y1 + y4, -50*u1 + x1 + 50*y1 - y4, u2 - y1, -u1 - u2 + y1 + 1, 50*u2 - y5, -50*u2 - x2 + y5 + 50, 65*y1, 65*u1 - 65*y1, 35*u2 + 65*y1 - y4 - y5]

sols = [solveset(t >= 0, y1, S.Reals) for t in list_of_inequalities if y1 in S(t).free_symbols]
sols

# [Interval(y4/50, oo),
#  Interval(-oo, u1 - x1/50 + y4/50),
#  Interval(-oo, y4/50),
#  Interval(u1 - x1/50 + y4/50, oo),
#  Interval(-oo, u2),
#  Interval(u1 + u2 - 1, oo),
#  Interval(0, oo),
#  Interval(-oo, u1),
#  Interval(-7*u2/13 + y4/65 + y5/65, oo)]

# extract the expressions, disregarding the infinity symbols
from sympy.core.numbers import Infinity, NegativeInfinity
test_inf = lambda x: x.has(Infinity) or x.has(NegativeInfinity)
[t[0] if not test_inf(t[0]) else t[1] for t in [s.args[:2] for s in sols]]
# [y4/50,
#  u1 - x1/50 + y4/50,
#  y4/50,
#  u1 - x1/50 + y4/50,
#  u2,
#  u1 + u2 - 1,
#  0,
#  u1,
#  -7*u2/13 + y4/65 + y5/65]
```

Comment: I have solved it differently, but your answer is much more flexible. Thanks!